# Populating edit form with db data returns Undefined variable Error - Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I am working in Laravel 7 trying to auto populate form data from the db using `value="{{ $task->task_name }}"` for example. but it is throwing an `Undefined Variable: task` in my `edit.blade.php` file.
I am getting the right task id as I can see it in the url. I have tried `{{ old('task_name') }}` and that just returned a the placeholder in the input field with no error. if I put `{{ old('task_name', $task->task_name) }}` it also throws an error. If anyone can help out with this issue, I would certainly appreciate it. I am using resources for my functions. Here is the code so far:

edit.blade.php (just relevant portion)

```
<form method="POST" action="tasks/{$id}" id="editForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mb-5">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
 {{ method_field('PUT') }}
     <div class="form-group">
       <input
         id="task_name"
         type="text"
         name="task_name"
         class="form-control"
         placeholder="Task name"
         value="{{ $task->task_name }}" />
      </div>
...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right">Edit Task</button>
</form>
```

In my tasks.blade.php (edit button only)

```
<div class="float-right" style="display: inline;">
    <a href="tasks/{{$task->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3 ml-2">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
    </a>
</div>
```

Finally, my TaskController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
    return view('tasks.edit');
}
 
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'task_name' => 'required',
        'task_description' => 'required',
    ]);

    $task = Task::find($id);
    $task->task_name = $request->input('task_name');
    $task->task_description = $request->input('task_description');
    $task->task_priority = $request->input('task_priority');
    $task->task_assigned_by = $request->input('task_assigned_by');
    $task->task_assigned_to = $request->input('task_assigned_to');
    $task->task_to_be_completed_date = $request->input('task_to_be_completed_date');
    $task->task_notes = $request->input('task_notes');
    $task->task_status = $request->input('task_status');
    $task->update();

    return redirect('/tasks')->with('success', 'Task Updated');
}
```

If I am missing any code or if you have any questions that would shed light on my query, please let me know so I can update my question. Thank you again in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `$task` variable into the view:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);

    return view('tasks.edit', ['task' => $task]);
}
```

---

Also, you can use the request `validation` method to extract the inputs that you need, after that, everything will be in the `$data` variable and you can easily update your model with one line of code.

I don't know how do you expect to receive the data, so I use `nullable` for the validation entries, you can take a look into all validations here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);

    $data = $request->validate([
        'task_name' => 'required',
        'task_description' => 'required',
        'task_priority' => 'nullable',
        'task_assigned_by' => 'nullable',
        'task_assigned_to' => 'nullable',
        'task_to_be_completed_date' => 'nullable',
        'task_notes' => 'nullable',
        'task_status' => 'nullable',
    ]);

    $task->update($data);

    return redirect('/tasks')->with('success', 'Task Updated');
}
```

This code will make the same this as the other, but it's much cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Jonathan, Thank you. I will mark this as the correct answer in about 6 minutes as it won't let me yet. It did the trick. Thank you so much. You're a bloody genious. Thank you a thousand times. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, you are welcome. Keep doing the good work! Can I give you some more tips? I would refactor that ```update``` method a little bit.

Comment: Will do. Thanks a lot.